# Is it always bad to force users to click to show them your products?

Tags: usability, design

Let me explain. Suppose you have a *a lot* of products (they might be physical goodies or not - like courses). Here you have some options to display your products:

1. You can create a very long list in your home page to display all your products at once. Users doesn't need to click to see your products but your home page will be obviously big;
2. You can create a specific page containing all your products. This implies forcing the user, once in the home page, to click to see the products;
3. You can create a specific number of pages containing your products organized by type (or whatever suits your product the best). This implies having a "main product page" that has links to all other sub-pages *or* having a lot of information in your home page.

So, in terms of product organization, 1 is the worst scenario and 3 is the best. Scenario 1 might give the user the sensation of no-organization and he might feel kinda lost but at the same time he don't need to click. Scenario 3 is way more organized and it might be a good thing but at the same time you made your user read a lot to find the specific group of products he wanted or made him click at least twice to see the product he wanted on the screen.

So, which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 3 is the best, without discussion**

**Option 1** is a nightmare. Just thinking of a long unorganized page with extreme cognitive load is reason enough to ditch it.

**Option 2** is even worse: you're offering the user the same thing as in **option 1**, only that with an added step!

Also, besides messing your product's list (reason enough but not the only one), keep in mind that in fact these first two options require more effort. Not nly cognitive, but physical: remember that in order to scroll... **You have to click as well!** So you're not savng effort at all in your first two scenarios. Quite the contrary, you're adding a lot of effort and friction with 0 benefit

Comment: Option 3 is definitely best. This actually sounds more like an Information Architecture design problem that needs to be solved first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of website you're creating but every site has business objectives and solutions to meet user's goals. What are you trying to solve in your website? And how do you solve it?

Users attention span is very short and each user has his own attitude, goals and the desire to get things done quickly when he lands on the website. Have you done card-sorting? Try this with your users. Probably this helps you understand what products naturally go together in order to organize and create intuitive structures and categories. (especially when you have lots of products). It's the users who use the site so let them tell you what's the most easiest way to organize and show your products. Here is the information about card sorting. https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html

Comment: Yes, go for option 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see **option 3** as the only option actually. Option 1 is like a big pile of clothes where you have to scramble for what you are looking for. Option 3 is where you have things organized, and to find what you are looking for, you know exactly where to go. 
Sort of similar to what you are saying, imaging going to a google play store or any other app store and having to scroll infinitely for what you are trying to look for. Instead, simply cartegorize based on whatever categories people would prefer searching for and let them look at all the options related to that category. That to me makes the most sense .

> So, go for option 3 and look at some sort of examples that have worked
>   when there are multiple products involved. e.g
>   https://play.google.com/store?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Reducing number of clicks needed until a user reaches a given goal is good only as long as you could keep clear navigation, clear picture of where the user had been, where he is now and where he is expected to go and so on. Reducing clicks at any cost is a common misconception in the web development world, but it is entirely wrong. Sometimes clicks are unavoidable and that is not a big deal if pages load quickly and UI is consistent so that users are not in confusion what to expect after a click. Many steps of low cognitive load are better than a single step of punishing cognitive load.